# C2DM quota limitation. Protocol/libraries replacements?

Tags: android, network-protocols, android-c2dm

I noticed that Google C2DM quota is limited to 200000 messages per day. This makes me thinking that it should be used for very simple use cases. Now I understand why IM services like skype or others have a service always running on the background. Does a library exist to manage a persistent connection to the server? I have tried XMPP with Smack api but even if it is very good for desktop stable connections, it is not so suitable for mobile ones (that have many problems). I would prefer a simpler one specific for mobile applications. Does it exist?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do here? Google C2DM quota is a soft-limit. If needed, you can email them and perhaps agree on some sort of business deal with them.

If you are looking for push-like experience, you can check out Urban Airship. They made their version of service that works on the Android devices without C2DM support.

Comment: Urban airship is quite expensive and it has limits (according to your money).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking out [Deacon](http://deacon.daverea.com/). There is Android specific code and it runs as a service in the background with a connection to your server.